# Asymptotic for restricted compositions into k parts

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

For every set of natural numbers $A$ and for all positive integers $n$, $k$, let $c_k^A(n)$ be the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts from $A$, that is, the number of $(a_1, \dots, a_k) \in A^k$ such that $a_1 + \cdots + a_k = n$.

I'm looking for asymptotic formulas for $c_k^A(n)$ as $n \to +\infty$ and $k \to +\infty$ (of course, in order to say anything interesting, some hypotheses on the relative grown of $n$ and $k$, and on the set $A$, are needed).

Where can I find such kind of results? I guess that something is surely known, but I keep finding only results with $A = \mathbb{N}$ and/or $k$ fixed.

Thank for any suggestion

Comment: That's the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $(\sum_{a\in A} x^a)^k$. Saddle point method is usually applied for asymptotics of such coefficients.

Comment: Fedor's comment seems to answer the question as best as it can be answered in this very general formulation. For example, if the generating function $\sum_{a\in A} x^a$ of $A$ is rational, then you should be able to extract precise asymptotics.

Comment: A nice video on restricted compositions  from Robert Sedgewick Analytic Combinatorics is available  at https://www.coursera.org/lecture/analytic-combinatorics/restricted-compositions-XOIXL It provide some particular generating functions for compositions and denumerations

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer with two simple cases first, followed by a more complex one, -a (weak) composition with bounded parts- that was asked several years ago and it did not get a complete answer. It is found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191510/diagonal-asymptotics-of-integer-compositions). I will apply a Mehler Heine-type method to get the dominant term asymptotics. (This is located towards the end of this post).

Compositions referred as counting multiset partitions into ordered multisets: A multiset (mset) is compound by a set of $k$ different objects mapped to a vector of integer multiplicities (repetitions) $[a_1,a_2,...,a_k]$ indicating that the multiset has a total of $n$ elements, all $a_1$ copies of the first object, $a_2$ of the second,... and $a_k$ of the last object, such that $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=n$. All permutations of this mset are partitioned in disjoint nonempty blocks, such that the union+ of these blocks is the multiset. The order of the elements inside these blocks is irrelevant and does not count while the order of all permuted blocks does matter.

$\left[a_1\right]=[n]$. There is just one object repeated $n$ times. This is elementary and it gives the classical definition of compositions. Partial and total number of compositions are$$c_k^A(n)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\ \wedge\ \sum_{k=1}^n c_k^A(n)=2^{n-1}$$  [image]

Just 1 Object Repeated $n=3$ times, total of 4 compositions. $k$ = number of blocks. Number of compositions are the number of rows with $k$ blocks. With 1 block there is 1 row, with 2 blocks there are 2 rows, with 3 blocks there is 1 row.

$\left[a_1,a_2,...,a_n\right]=[1,1,...,1]$. There are $n$ different objects and mutiset has one of each. In this case, there is no a common name to enumerate these posets. Generalized compositions, chains, preferential arrangement or pattern of length $n$ have been used. Cardinality (total number of compositions. -See Note-) corresponds to Fubini's numbers, also known as ordered Bell Numbers, $\sum_{k=1}^n k!S(n,k)$ where $S(n,k)$ are Stirling numbers of 2nd kind. This gives sequence 1, 3, 13, 75, 541, 4683, 47293,... ([OEIS A000670](https://oeis.org/A000670)). Generating function is $g(z)=(2-e^z)^{-1}$. In this case from 5.2.8 in Wilf's Generatingfunctionology book (See reference below), partial and total number of compositions are respectively

$$c_k^A(n)=k!S(n,k)\ \wedge \ \sum_{k=1}^n c_k^A(n) \sim \frac{1}{2}n!\cdot (\log_2e)^{n+1}\  \ \mathrm{as}\ n\rightarrow\infty$$ **Note:** This corresponds to Exercise 4.16* in Combinatorics of compositions and words (Silvia Heubach, Toufik Mansour) Book. This case also corresponds to Stanley R. Enumerative Combinatorics (1986, Wadsworth) Ch.3 Posets. Examples 3.15.9 & 3.15.10 pg. 145-146 or (2012, Vol I. 2nd Ed. Cambridge), examples 3.18.9 & 3.18.10 pg. 326, where they are called *chains* (ordered partitions of $n$ into $k$ non-empty blocks).

[image]

$n=3$ different objects. Total of 13 compositions (chains). $k$ = number of blocks. Number of compositions or chains are the number of rows with $k$ blocks. With 1 block there is 1 row, with 2 blocks there are 6 rows, with 3 blocks there are 6 rows. Note that if $B=C=D$ compositions shrink to the former case.

There are other very interesting cases. For instance 2 objects repeated $[a_1,a_2]=[p,n-p]$ times $0<p<n$. Asymptotics for the total number of these generalized compositions, that is between the two previous cases, I guess it has been analyzed but I have not found it. I leave the example here

[image]

$n=3,\ p=2$. A total number of 8 = 1 + 4 + 3 generalized compositions.

Just to wrap up this section, there is a brief discussion in the comments that compositions are only about sets of integers and not other sets. I obviously agree about that since on the one hand, compositions, as they are defined, only refer to counting how a number breaks down into the sum of its parts (sets are implicit) and on the other hand, the enumeration of the posets shown in this answer, whatever they are named, are generalized compositions over the integers (in this case, mset multiplicities). I sincerely hope I have made this matter as clear as possible.

---

This section fits on a special case of the question made. It answers an [old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191510/diagonal-asymptotics-of-integer-compositions) for the asymptotics of a (weak) composition of a positive integer $n$ into $k$ parts (an ordered sequence of nonnegative integers $[a_1,a_2,…,a_k]$ such that $∑_{i=1}^k a_i =n$ with the parts conditioned by $a_i ∈ [0,1,…,j−1]$). The number of such compositions $\ c_{k,j}^A(n)=\kappa(n,j,k)$ satisfies, $$\kappa(n,j,k) = \sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^\ell {k \choose \ell} {k-j\ell+n-1 \choose k-1}$$

as it is pointed out in Stanley, Richard P. "Enumerative Combinatorics. Vol I". 2nd Printing. Cambridge 1998, Supplementary Problems Ch. 1 Exercise 3 pg. 307.

This is a terminating hypergeometric function. It corresponds to a polynomial of degree $k$ expressible as an scaled$\ _2\Psi_1^*$ Fox-Wright Function (evaluated at $z=-1$). We will use the method of Mehler-Heine to find the asymptotics for $n=k\,\lambda,\ 0<\lambda<j-1$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ of this expression as it is indicated in [*Bracciali and Moreno-Balcazar* report](https://publications.mfo.de/bitstream/handle/mfo/1069/OWP2013_23.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (Sect 2. pg 3). Note that asymptotics is respect the parameters of $\ _2\Psi_1^*$ and not the function variable $z$. For $\alpha=j-\lambda-1>0$ we have $$c_{k,j}^A(k\,\lambda) = \frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k)}\cdot\sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{(-k)_\ell}{\ell!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(j\,\ell-k\,\alpha)}{\Gamma(j\,\ell-k\,(\alpha+1)+1)}$$ $(a)_b=\Gamma(a+b)/\Gamma(a)$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Therefore, $$c_{k,j}^A(k\,\lambda)=F(k,\alpha)\cdot S(k,\alpha)$$ $$S(k,\alpha)=\sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{(-k)_\ell}{\ell!}\cdot\frac{(-k\,\alpha)_{j\,\ell}}{(-k\,(\alpha+1)+1)_{j\,\ell}}$$  $$F(k,\alpha)=\frac{(-1)^k}{\Gamma(k)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(-k\,\alpha)}{\Gamma(-k\,(\alpha+1)+1)}$$ The approach is as follows (Mehler-Heine), for the sum $S$ apply Lebesgue's dominance to move the upper limit to $\infty$ and use $(\beta\,k+\gamma)_m\sim (\beta\,k+\gamma)^m\sim (\beta\,k)^m$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. By doing this, the price we pay is that all asymptotic expansion of this sum is lost except the leading or dominant factor which is fully retained preserving uniform asymptotic convergence. This is enough to answer the original question. Therefore we get as $k\rightarrow\infty$ , $$S(k,\alpha)\sim\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{(-k)^\ell}{\ell!}\cdot\frac{(-k\,\alpha)^{j\,\ell}}{(-k\,(\alpha+1))^{j\,\ell}}=e^{-k\,\left[\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\right]^j}$$ For the factor $F$ use reflection formula for the gammas and then Stirling's approximation. This gives $$F(k,\alpha)=\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(k\,(\alpha+1))}{\Gamma(k\,\alpha+1)}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\binom{k(\alpha+1)}{k}$$ $$F(k,\alpha)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,k}}\cdot\frac{(\alpha+1)^{k(\alpha+1)+\frac{1}{2}}}{\alpha^{k\,\alpha+\frac{3}{2}}}$$ Finally for $\alpha=j-\lambda-1$ we get as $k\rightarrow\infty$ $$c_{k,j}^A(\lambda\,k)=\kappa(\lambda\,k,j,k)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\,k}}\cdot\frac{(\alpha+1)^{k(\alpha+1)+\frac{1}{2}}}{\alpha^{k\,\alpha+\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot e^{-k\,\left[\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\right]^j}$$

---

Asymptotic for restricted compositions having the same number of parts is found [here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0166218X11005002?token=439982CBC15ADDAD6D40225D0D4B6870B47F2F7688E90F3472E57AA84027C7CA692DD0D35AAFD94F73604B4E9115276A&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220406171248), also in [ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6116.pdf)

*Wilf, Herbert S.*, Generatingfunctionology., Boston, MA: Academic Press. x, 228 p. (1994). [ZBL0831.05001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0831.05001).

*Stanley, Richard P.*, Enumerative combinatorics. Vol. I, The Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole Mathematics Series. Monterey, California: Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole Advanced Books & Software. xi, 306 p. (1986). [ZBL0608.05001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0608.05001).

*Cleonice F. Bracciali, Juan Jose Moreno-Balcazar*. Mehler-Heine Asymptotics of a Class of Generalized Hypergeometric Polynomials. Oberwolfach WP 2013 - 23. Mathematisches Forschungsinstitut Oberwolfach gGmbH. Oberwolfach Preprints (OWP) ISSN 1864-7596. ([link here](https://publications.mfo.de/handle/mfo/1069))

---

Comment: I am very confused by this answer.

Comment: @Sam_Hopkins. I would appreciate if you can spread yourself, Thnks

Comment: In particular, I don't get what is meant by ``$a_1=\cdots=a_k=1$'': in the terminology of the question-asker, the $a_i$ are the parts of the composition (whereas $A$ is the set of allowed parts). And $2^{n-1}$ is well-known to be the total number of compositions of $n$; but what happened to the parameter $k$, keeping track of the number of parts? If we really have $n=k$ then there is only one composition of $n$: $n=1+1+\ldots+1$.

Comment: Ahhh, now I think I might see what's going on: you're talking about set partitions. But the question is just about compositions of an integer (into a certain number of parts, which come from some fixed set).

Comment: @Sam_Hopkins. Multisets are 'sets' where repetitions of objects are allowed. Compositions arise from many sources. One of them is multiset partitions into ordered multisets. It is implemented in Sage https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/multiset_partition_into_sets_ordered.html

Comment: @Sam_Hopkins In fact, you can use any alphabet of symbols different from natural numbers to generate these permuted blocks and enumerate them.

Comment: The question is about compositions of an integer in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics). I think you are answering a different question.

Comment: @Sam_Hopkins. It is the same as it is pointed out there. However I made some amendments to leave it clearer. Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: I reiterate that the question is not about set compositions, it is about *integer* compositions.

Comment: @Sam_Hopkins. Yes, you are absolutely right. This is not about set compositions. It has no meaning. It is about integer compositions. Multisets are compound of distinct objects and integer multiplicities mapped 1-to-1, Compositions are made over these integers. I'll set it clearer

Answer (score 0):

A great resource is the book *Combinatorics of Compositions and Words*, Silvia Heubach and Toufik Mansour, CRC Press, 2010.  Chapter 8 is "Asymptotics for Compositions."

Comment: I agree that it is a great resource on compositions, but I checked that chapter and, unfortunately, there's no result about compositions with parts restricted to a set A.

Comment: Oops.  They introduce restricted parts $A$ in $\S$3.3 and carefully prove things in that generality through chapter 5, but then most of chapter 8 is about unrestricted compositions or Carlitz compositions.  Exceptions are Example 8.26 with $A=\{1,2\}$ and parts of $\S$8.4 which might be relevant, e.g., the asymptotics of the largest part in Theorem 8.39.